# Error installing v8@3.15 on Macbook Pro Ventura with homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, therubyracer, libv8

The following error it shows:

```
Error: v8@3.15 has been disabled because it depends on Python 2 to build!
```

Check Formula on homebrew website, it says it is disabled. ref: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/v8@3.15

Comment: Installing historical versions of V8 is going to be increasingly difficult if not impossible as time goes on.